# ANT - How do I get list of available tasks from ant library using Java

Tags: java, ant

I need to get a list of available ant tasks at runtime. Basically use the ant library included in the user class path and list all the ant tasks.

Answer (score 1):

As vanilla ant has its taskdefs defined via plain property file in ant.jar, you may use :

```
<project>
 <property url="jar:file:/path/to/your/ANT_HOME/ant.jar!/org/apache/tools/ant/taskdefs/defaults.properties" prefix="antcoretasks"/>
 <echoproperties prefix="antcoretasks"/>
</project>
```

to list the ant core tasks, output :

```
[echoproperties] #Ant properties
[echoproperties] #Sat Apr 14 21:23:41 CEST 2012
[echoproperties] antcoretasks.ant=org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Ant
[echoproperties] antcoretasks.antcall=org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.CallTarget
[echoproperties] antcoretasks.antlr=org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.ANTLR
[echoproperties] antcoretasks.antstructure=org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.AntStructure
[echoproperties] antcoretasks.antversion=org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.condition.AntVersion
... etc.
```

or write them to a file :

```
<echoproperties prefix="antcoretasks" destfile="some.file"/>
```

If there are any further requirements, you have to provide more details in your question.

Comment: can also use Groovy - AntBuilder().antProject.taskDefinitions, But I like your suggestion better. Thanks

Comment: didn't know, that Groovy is an option for you. i like Groovy and use it very often in and outside ant.